# Changing point labels to specific string values using iOS charts?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I'm playing with the label feature provided in the ios-charts library and I'd like to be able to set a custom label (as a string) rather than have the program automatically set the label to the y value of that point.

[image]

I've googled around and can't find anyone with any similar issues so was wondering if anyone knew how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my experience, you can achieve this with the help of `ChartFormatter` in `Charts` library.

Use below code to show string values on your Charts.

**Set Value Formatter:**

```
let chartFormatter = BarChartFormatter(labels: xValues)
let xAxis = XAxis()
xAxis.valueFormatter = chartFormatter
self.xAxis.valueFormatter = xAxis.valueFormatter
```

**Implement Valuformatter methods:**

```
private class BarChartFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {

        var labels: [String] = []

        func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
            return labels[Int(value)]
        }

        init(labels: [String]) {
            super.init()
            self.labels = labels
        }
    }
```

By adding above code for your respective charts you can set string values on your `XAxis`.

> Note: Replace BarChartFormatter with your Chart type.

Hope this will helps!

Comment: The original question is asking about the labels above the points, rather than the xAxis labels (see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239920/).